# How to let user download zip file using vaadin file downloader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I've followed this [topic](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file) and it perfectly works. Here's the function to create resource for file downloader

```
 private StreamResource createResource() {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            String text = "My image";

            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(100, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            bi.getGraphics().drawChars(text.toCharArray(), 0, text.length(), 10, 20);

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bos);
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }, "myImage.png");
}
```

but i don't know how to make it create a resource of zip file. Do i need to create many resources?. Thank you

Comment: If you want to make a ZIP file, follow [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html) tutorial at section "Compressing and Archiving Data in a ZIP File".

Comment: If you came up with a solution, please share it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that i figured out myself

```
private StreamResource createZipResource()
{ 
    return new StreamResource(new StreamSource()
    { 
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream()
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try
            {
                ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

                for (int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (listData.get(i).contains(".txt"))
                    { 
                        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(listData.get(i) + ".txt"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        out.write(listData.get(i).getBytes());                            
                    } 
                }
                out.close();
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem writing ZIP file: " + e);
            }
            return null; 
        }
    },"Filename.zip"); 
}
```